# Python: asserting that I'm running on POSIX?

Tags: python, posix

I'm writing some POSIX-specific code, and although I'm not supporting other platforms I'd like to make sure they get a nice clear error at import time rather than strange errors, if they tried to use my code.

Is there a neat way to check that?  I guess I could to an `import posix` and catch the `ImportError` but that seems kind of verbose.

Comment: Isn't that what `os.name` tells you?  What's wrong with `os.name`?

Comment: S.Lott: yep, you've answered my question (but in a comment)

Comment: Catch the errors and print a warning "only POSIX supported". Some non-POSIX systems might actually work, and you'd be doing those users a disservice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [`os.name`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.name):

> The name of the operating system dependent module imported. The
>   following names have currently been registered: 'posix', 'nt', 'os2',
>   'ce', 'java', 'riscos'.

There are also [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform) and [`os.uname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.uname) if you require finer granularity.

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_3.1#POSIX : "Windows NT 3.1 included a subsystem that was minimally POSIX-compatible." :)

Answer (score 3):

you can:

```
def is_posix():
    try:
        import posix
        return True
    except ImportError:
        return False
```

You can also parse `sys.platform` or `os.uname()[0]`, but I think it's more natural to ask "*does your system has that feature*" rather than "*is you system one of ..., because I know they have that feature now*".

Answer (score 0):

instead of import posix you should import os, so you can have a subset of instruction available to the user (but not the posix specific ones) then you could use the [sys.platform](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) feature to check on which platform the user is running your code and then throw an exception or not :)

Comment: ehm my answer is kinda incomplete: the subset of instructions i was talking about is just for non-POSIX users, while the posix users will have all those available :)